# Invoking JS in .net Maui Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have a page called
`display.blazor`. The code behind is stored in in `display.blazor.cs` (Same folder).
Then I have some JS in scripts.js (path is `wwwroot/js/script.js`)

At first, I wanted to invoke JS via the code behind. I managed this using                       `jsModule = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/script.js");`

I know that the file is there and I can successfully execute from it.

*however*

I want to invoke js functions from the blazor file itself.

for example:

`<input type="button" onclick="hello();" value="Display">`

The above did not work.

What did I try?

In the index.html I placed this:

```
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webview.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script src="~/js/BFA.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

It does not work. I also tried to place js in a file called `display.blazor.js`

In the .csproj file i had noted this which I found suspicious so I removed it

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\js\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried many different things but I just can't invoke JS from my .blazor files.

Comment: *"I know that the file is there and I can successfully execute from it."* Can you get it to work indirectly? From HTML call a c# code behind method, which in turn calls JS Display? If so, add to question those two bits of code (HTML; code behind method). That would be the work-around, right? I don't use Blazor, but presumably it is looking for a c# method, not a JS one.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely looking for c# method.